# Emit a custom metadata from seed URLs through all child discovered URLs for all depth

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I have a Storm Crawler based project which index all contents and status in Solr collections. For each seedUrl, I have some metadata which needs to be emitted through all child of each seed URLs. For example, I have a data structure similar to this:

<crawlId, seedUrl, myMetadata>

How can I emit the crawlId and corresponding metaData to all discovered children for each seedUrl? Is there available any built-in capability that we can use from that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*metadata.transfer* is what you need, [see conf from the archetype](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/crawler-conf.yaml#L25)